# How to pass unsigned char* to managed method in C++/CLI efficiently?

Tags: arrays, .net, c++-cli

Consider the following managed class:

```
public ref class DataProvider
{
  public: 
    static int ReadData(void* handlePtr, unsigned char* buffer, int cnt)
    {
      if (handlePtr == nullptr)
      {
        return -1;
      }

      GCHandle handle = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr::IntPtr(handlePtr));
      System::IO::Stream^ _stream = dynamic_cast<System::IO::Stream^>(handle.Target);
      if (_stream == nullptr)
      {
        return -1;
      }

      array<unsigned char>^ data = gcnew array<unsigned char>(cnt);
      pin_ptr<unsigned char> dataPtr = &data[0];
      int read = stream->Read(data, 0, cnt);
      if (read > 0)
      {
        memcpy(buffer, dataPtr, cnt);
      }
      return read;
    }
}
```

`ReadData` method is called via callback from the unmanaged code. It works, but allocates temporary `data` buffer. It looks excessive.

**Question**: Is it possible to pass original `buffer` into `stream->Read` method and eliminate allocation of this extra `data` buffer?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maoni/2004/06/03/gc-performance-counters/

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot for the comment. I will check performance counters, but this method is the core component and executed at a very high rate. I need to be sure it's not possible to pass already allocated buffer into the managed method to reduce memory traffic.